# Google Built CentOS Image - Anyone have a download for this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos8

I've looked for this across the web a few times, and I feel like this hasn't been asked exactly, or I may just be getting bogged down with the wrong syntax.  Hoping to get an easy answer here (yes, you can't get this, is an acceptable answer).

The variations from the base CentOS image are listed here: [Link to GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/os-details?authuser=2)

However, they don't actually provide a download for this image.  I'm trying to get a local VM running in VMWare with this image.

I feel as though they'd provide this to their clients to make it easier to prepare for use of their product, but I'm not finding it anywhere.

If anyone could toss me a link to a pre-configured CentOS ISO with the minor changes, I'd definitely take that as an alternative.  I'm just not confident in my skills with Linux enough to configure the firewall properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCP doesn't support Google-provied images for exporting. However, they support exporting images for custom images.

I don't have any experience about image exporting, but I think this works.

1. Create custom images

You can create custom images based on your GCE VM instance.

Go navigation -> Compute engine -> images page.

You can create custom image via disk or snapshot in this page.

Select one and create a custom image.

[image]

2. Export your image

After creating custom image successfully, Go custom image page and click "export" on upper side.

Select export format and GCS destination. then click export.

[image]

Now you have an image in the Google Cloud storage.

Download image file and import to your local VM machine.

Comment: This will definitely be my solution.  You have taught me something new, and this will definitely solve my problem.  Thanks a lot.  I'd tried to make my own image in the past unsuccessfully, and this will definitely save me a lot of effort in the future.

You're awesome :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)